# how to find the work done in pumping fluid out of a tank using integration and formula?

Tags: calculus, integration, physics

For example, a half-full cylindrical tank that holds a liquid that is 12 pounds per cubic foot(4ft radius by 8 ft tall). How do we find the work done in pumping the fluid out of the tank from the top outlet?

I tried using Work = Force * distance:

- determined the force is the volume and weight of the liquid, $\pi*(4)^2 * 8/2 * 12 = 768\pi$
- Because work is the integral of force:  Work = $\int_{4}^{8}768 \pi dx = 3072\pi$ , which is incorrect (Ans: 4608ft-lb)

Where have I gone wrong here, did I get the value of the force wrong, where is my knowledge gap?

Comment: What does $x$ signify in your integral?

Comment: Change in distance?

Comment: A change in distance could work, but you have to be much, much more precise than that in how you think about it. First, *what object* undergoes a change in distance? Second, how is this distance *measured*? Distance is from point A to point B; what is point A, what is point B? Is it straight line distance, distance along a curve, only the horizontal component of distance, only the vertical component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The work done to pump out liquid from the top outlet is different for the liquid at different depths.

Volume of infinitely thin layer of liquid ($dx$) at   depth $x$ from top is,

$dV = \pi \cdot 4^2  \cdot dx = 16 \pi ~ dx ~ $ and this liquid needs to be taken $x$ distance against gravity.

So work done in pumping out the liquid in unit ft-lb is,

$ \displaystyle \int_4^8 \rho~ x ~ dV $

where $\rho = 12 $ lb / ft$^3$

Comment: Incorrect though, the correct answer was 4608 ft-lb. $\displaystyle \int_4^8 \rho~ x ~ dV \implies \displaystyle \int_4^8 12 x ~ dV= 288$ ?

Comment: $dV = 16 \pi dx$, right?

Comment: So it is $ \int_4^8 (12 \cdot 16 \pi) x ~ dx = 4608 \pi $